# Maximo REST API can't be called thousands of times

Tags: garbage-collection, websphere, maximo

I'm using the REST API in Maximo 7.5 (and 7.6)  to create thousands of meter readings (mxmeterdata).  However, Oracle quickly reaches the max allowed limit of processes and/or sessions.  Changing the allowed limit in Oracle would only delay the inevitable: once the limit has been reached, no further meter readings can be created until the number of inactive sessions has dropped.

I've looked at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/garbage_collection_and_connection_leak29?lang=en and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21640951 which suggest changing garbage collection settings.  On WebLogic, I managed to keep the inactive session count down by shrinking the Java heap nursery size down.  On WebSphere, this did not help, as neither did forcing garbage collections regularly.

What is the recommended way to permit calling the REST API thousands of times?  Are there specific configuration settings in Maximo, Oracle, or WebSphere that I should change to support this?

Thanks

Comment: IBM suggested it may be a bug:  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0579e876-aae8-4494-a7e8-de7c219e48cb

Answer (score 0):

To help leaked database connections to be collected faster, you could try setting mxe.db.longruntimelimit=5 (default is 180) and mxe.db.closelongrunconn=true (default is false) and creating mxe.db.detectlongrunconninterval=5 (default is 30).

The above is from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/Maximo_How_to_solve_database_connection_leak?lang=en.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, the inactive queries are very fast.  The number of open sessions reaches its limit in about 10 seconds.  I reached out to ibm and they suggested I report it as a bug.  It is not a problem for assets, but it is for meter data.